# Using variables in javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

This is a short question but I am using chart.js library and my code is:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
totalCost = (inputWatts * price + varServiceFees + inputServiceTrips).toFixed(0);
totalFactor = (totalCost / (inputWatts * price)).toFixed(2);

if (selected === 'bService') {
    totalCostService = totalCost;
} else if (selected === 'bMicro') {
    totalCostMicro = totalCost;
} else {
    totalCostTypical = totalCost;
}

var data = [
    {
        value: totalCostService,
        color: '#f7464a'
    },
    {
        value: totalCostMicro,
        color: '#46bfbd'
    },
    {
        value: totalCostTypical,
        color: '#fdb45c'
    }

], graph = new Chart(document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d')).Doughnut(data);
```

My problem is that when using the totalCost variable nothing happens, if I replace these with numbers such as 30 though it is working fine. I know the variable is working because I am displaying it on my web page and it shows a valid number. I even have my code check `isNaN === false`. Any help would be wonderful, thanks!

**EDIT**

I replaced `value: totalCostMicro` and `value: totalCostTypical` both with `value: 30` while debugging and messed with totalCostService only. Above you can see that totalCostService is really totalCost which is inputWatts * price etc, so what I did was do `value: inputWatts` which worked, and then tried `value: price` and so on, all working.  But the general variable totalCost will not work and I think it may be because of the .toFixed(0) but need this to round the number off. Any alternatives?

Comment: I would guess your `totalCost...` variables aren't in scope, so they are undefined. But thats hard to tell without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Where are your variables defined? I don't see any `totalCost` variable neither.

Comment: Where are `totalCostService`, `totalCostMicro` and `totalCostTypical` defined?

Comment: Sorry guys I updated the OP. I can tell you that totalCost does come out to be a valid number and is displayed on my web page but maybe the toFixed part messes it up or something. I am not sure to be honest and that's why I am here aha. I could post more code if needed, but just as a note I did replace totalCost with 30 just to test and it did work, so more code may be needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for wasting everyone's time but just by asking the question I learned what was wrong. The `toFixed(0)` caused the error, if you know why please comment as I am curious, but now all is working. Thanks again for everyone's help, this is the best community!

Comment: I tried to debug your code, but everything seems fine to me. What part of the `.toFixed()` method doesn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not figure this out, it may not have been the `.toFixed()` that wasn't working, but removing this did fix my problem.

Comment: If you don't want further assistance with this question, you should accept your own answer, so it doesn't appear unanswered. If you still want assistance, then please clarify what exactly went wrong a provide a minimal use case :)

Comment: Says I can't accept the answer for another day but will be sure to do so asap (: thanks for all the help guys!